# Forbidden error while using Jupyter Notebook in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cookies, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Recently I can't save any jupyter notebook on Firefox and I see the "Forbidden" yellow error. The problem is occurring only in firefox and the Chrome works fine.

I've checked the browser's settings and cookies storing is enabled, AdBlock is disabled and the Notebook library and Firefox are the latest versions.